# resolving a reticulate conda normalizePath error

Tags: r, conda, reticulate, mamba

I recently switched the conda solver from classic to libmamba. Then I removed mamba. Conda seems to work fine, but I started getting a reticulate error in R:

```
> reticulate::use_condaenv("base")
> reticulate::use_condaenv("r-reticulate")
Error in normalizePath(conda, winslash = "/", mustWork = TRUE) : 
  path[1]="/path/miniconda3/bin/mamba": No such file or directory
```

I am not sure why it is looking for mamba. If I just run `conda activate r-reticulate` in the terminal, there is no error. It only happens in R. Curiously, I have multiple versions of R and I only see this in one of them. Is there a fix?

Comment: I think the location of the Conda binary (this case `mamba`) can get specified (and possibly cached) via `RETICULATE_CONDA` environment variable, or from the option `getOption("reticulate.conda_binary")`. Maybe check to be sure those aren't persisting somehow.

Comment: E.g., [the source code states](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/blob/9163ac38a731b72dc68fea69a9bcad2933e5b079/R/use_python.R#L22) that a `.Renviron` in a project or `~/.Renviron` at user level can define these.